# merge groups of lines with sed

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I would like to merge each group of lines from file :

```
    <tr>
            <td >441</td>
            <td >S</td>
            <td >0,74</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td >442</td>
            <td >S</td>
            <td >0,14</td>
    </tr>
```

to one line (number of spaces or tabs between td's is not important for me):

```
    <tr> <td >441</td> <td >S</td> <td >0,74</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td >442</td> <td >S</td> <td >0,14</td> </tr>
```

Each group ( with ':set line' in vi ) looks like this :

```
     ^I<tr>$
     ^I^I<td >441</td>$
     ^I^I<td >S</td>$
     ^I^I<td >0,74</td>$
     ^I</tr>$
```

I have real problem to do it myself with sed command. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using perl instead of sed.  I find this solution simpler to read and understand.

```
perl -pe 's|\n|| ; s|</tr>|</tr>\n|' file
```

output:

```
<tr>    <td >441</td>   <td >S</td>     <td >0,74</td></tr>
<tr>    <td >442</td>   <td >S</td>     <td >0,14</td></tr>
```

Comment: Works in my system.

Answer (score 2):

With sed, you can do this:

```
$ cat inf
    <tr>
            <td >441</td>
            <td >S</td>
            <td >0,74</td>
    </tr>
$ sed ':a;N;s/\n//;ta' inf
    <tr>            <td >441</td>           <td >S</td>         <td >0,74</td>  </tr>
```

which does this:

- `:a` makes a label
- `N` will append the current line to the buffer, thus allowing for the next command
- `s/\n//` will replace the new line from the previous command with nothing, thus effectively joining the lines
- `ta` is "goto :a"

An easier way is to use `tr`:

```
$ cat inf
    <tr>
            <td >441</td>
            <td >S</td>
            <td >0,74</td>
    </tr>
$ cat inf|tr -d '\n'
    <tr>            <td >441</td>           <td >S</td>         <td >0,74</td>  </tr>
```

where `-d '\n'` means "delete new line".

EDIT: Misunderstood what you want. If you want to process multiple of the above groups in one input stream, here's what you can do with `sed`:

```
$ cat inf
  foo
  baz
    <tr>
            <td >441</td>
            <td >S</td>
            <td >0,74</td>
    </tr>
  fizz
  buzz
    <tr>
            <td >441</td>
            <td >S</td>
            <td >0,74</td>
    </tr>
  tomato
  potato
$ sed -r '/<tr/{:a;N;s/[\t\n]//g;/<\/tr/!ba}' inf
  foo
  baz
<tr><td >441</td><td >S</td><td >0,74</td></tr>
  fizz
  buzz
<tr><td >441</td><td >S</td><td >0,74</td></tr>
  tomato
  potato
```

As others have mentioned, you can do this in a bit more readable form with `awk` or `perl` or python, but please note one thing - regexp is not powerful enough to parse HTML or XML. See this one for a good discussion:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Hope this helps.

Comment: maybe its because I use 'FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE'. The s/\n// replace doesn't work as it should ( it seems not to find any \n ). 'tr' command makes only one very long line - I would like that each group be in separate line.

Comment: @katosheen Misunderstood what you meant - see my edit and obviously take a look at other answers, too. I think `perl` or `awk` solutions are more readable here, in case you don't need to use `sed` exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

```
# cat foo.html | xargs echo -n
<tr> <td >441</td> <td >S</td> <td >0,74</td> </tr>
```

Or to strip all spaces...

```
# cat foo.html | xargs -n1 echo -n
<tr><td>441</td><td>S</td><td>0,74</td></tr>
```

You can achieve this affect right from inside vi just by doing:

```
!!xargs echo -n
```

Comment: I like this for this feel simpler, but does it work in aix ? Also, didn't it simply remove all newline ? how to handles the 2 line arguments ?

Comment: If your file is extremely regular, you can just play with the number of arguments that xargs will handle at once.  With your example text, "cat foo.html | xargs -n8 echo" works perfectly.

Comment: As for aix, if the gnu utils exist on aix, then you should be good to go.  I'd be surprised if they didn't, but my total lifetime minutes spent at an aix prompt is about 10, so I'm not qualified to answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '/<tr>/,/<\/tr>/{printf("%s", $0)};/<\/tr/{printf("\n")}' file
```

---

```
$ cat file
    <tr>
        <td >441</td>
        <td >S</td>
        <td >0,74</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >442</td>
        <td >S</td>
        <td >0,14</td>
    </tr>

$  awk '/<tr>/,/<\/tr>/{printf("%s", $0)};/<\/tr/{printf("\n")}' file
    <tr>    <td >441</td>   <td >S</td>     <td >0,74</td> </tr>
    <tr>    <td >442</td>   <td >S</td>     <td >0,14</td> </tr>
```

Comment: Works in my system.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r ':k /<tr>/,/<\/tr>/{/<\/tr>/! {N;s/\n/ /;tk}}' file
```

---

```
$ cat file
    <tr>
        <td >441</td>
        <td >S</td>
        <td >0,74</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >442</td>
        <td >S</td>
        <td >0,14</td>
    </tr>

$ sed -r ':k /<tr>/,/<\/tr>/{/<\/tr>/! {N;s/\n/ /;tk}}' file
    <tr>    <td >441</td>   <td >S</td>     <td >0,74</td> </tr>
    <tr>    <td >442</td>   <td >S</td>     <td >0,14</td> </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure of the length of the groups, and you still want to use `sed`, you could consider a variation on the following:

`sed -e 'N;N;N;N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\2\3\4\5/'`

notice how this solution lets you discard or rearrange lines, but as said it does depend on the consistent length of the groups in your input file.